# Odd TypeError with Multi Process Python Module

Tags: python, web.py, multiprocess

I'm trying to start a web.py server using this code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=app.run) #starts the web.py server
    p.start()
    main() #starts a main listening loop for errors, testing and logging
    p.join()
```

where

```
app = web.application(urls, globals()) #part of the web.py framework... starts the REST server
```

But I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "apitest.py", line 90, in <module>
p = Process(target=app.run)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

I've googled everwhere but i can't find what's going on... can anybody help?

Thank you!

Comment: Namespace conflict? You're not calling the process you think you are. Try importing Process as something else or in another namespace and you should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by agf in the comments, your namespaces are likely stepping on each other, so the name `Process` isn't the `Process` that you think it is. To fix this, change the way you're importing `Process` to be more explicit:

```
import multiprocessing

# ...all your other code...

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=app.run) # starts the web.py server
```